# Read Access Violation and Write Access Violation when trying to access a Struct pointer defined globally

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, struct

My question might be a little big and silly. I'm still learning C++.
So please bear with me.

I'm implementing a simulator for a simple 5 stage CPU.

I have defined a struct in `functions.h` and I instantiated the struct with different pointers in `functions.cpp` in global namespace. I have multiple functions which write to and read from this struct without these structs being fed as arguments. However I'm getting "NullPtr" error and "read access violation" and I have been trying to fix it for hours now. I don't know what's going on.

This is how my code looks like in an overview.

functions.h:

```
namespace functions{

typedef array<int, 2> src_reg;

struct instruction_info {

    string instruction_type = "NOP";
    string instruction_string;
    vector<src_reg> source_registers;
    int literal = NULL;
    bool update_zero = true;
    array<int,2> destination_register;
    int target_memory_address = NULL;
    int target_memory_data = NULL;          
};


struct stage_struct {

    bool psw_access = true;
    instruction_info* input_instruction;
    instruction_info* output_instruction;
    bool stalled = false;
    int program_counter = 4000;
    bool finished = false;

};

}
```

I then went ahead and instantiated them and they look like this:

functions.cpp

```
using namespace functions;
stage_struct stage_memory_p;
stage_struct stage_write_back_p;
stage_struct* stage_memory = &stage_memory_p;
stage_struct* stage_write_back = &stage_write_back_p;
```

I then call them from all the stages. But it throws exceptions.

```
int functions::decode_rf() {

    if ((stage_decode_rf->input_instruction->instruction_string == "NOP"))
        return 0;
    ...
}
```

It gives me "Read access violation" error here. I'm new to C++ and I really don't understand what this signifies.

And I got another problem which I think is similar to this. This is also part of the same code.

functions.h:

```
typedef struct Code_Line {

    int file_line_number = NULL;
    int address = NULL;
    string instruction_string = "";

}code_line;


struct code_memory {
    array<code_line, 1000> array_code_line;
};
```

functions.cpp:

```
code_memory *instructions;
code_line *code_lines;

int functions::initialize_i_memory(string file_name) {

    ifstream insts;
    string one_line;

    insts.open(file_name);

    if (!insts) {
        cout << "There was an error opening the instructions file" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "File loaded successfully. Now writing them into instruction memory" << endl;

    int cnt = 0;

    while (getline(insts, one_line)) {

        instructions->array_code_line[cnt].address = (4000 + (cnt * 4));
        instructions->array_code_line[cnt].file_line_number = (cnt + 1);
        instructions->array_code_line[cnt].instruction_string = one_line;
        cnt++;
    }

    insts.close();
    return cnt;
}
```

And then I call it from the `main()` function:

```
int total_instructions = initialize_i_memory("input.txt");
```

It now throws "Write Access Violation" error.

Could anyone please explain me why this is happening?

I would be really thankful if someone tries to approach the problem in a more general way and provide a solution.

If possible, please also feel free to post any blogs/tutorials about this.

Comment: `int literal = NULL;` Why do you use NULL for an int?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to step through your code, one line at a time, examining the values of all variables on each step, so you can easily follow your program's execution, line by line, what was the reason for your program crashing? Did you know that using a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions? You will have to figure this out yourself, with your debugger; it is unlikely that anyone can give you an answer because the shown code fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mcve], as described in [help].

Comment: Debugging is definitely a required skill -- debugging using a debugger is optional.  Some of us still prefer debug-by-printf-insertion ;)

Comment: Unrelated: C++ doesn't force you to `typedef struct Code_Line { ... }code_line;` You can simply `struct code_line{ ... };` and walk away a happy coder.

Comment: I tried initializing int with some value(NULL). Does that cause any problem?. I will change it to 0.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Buddy I'm just learning C++. Could you provide me any great link to learn debugging?

Comment: @ArvindMadan the point is `NULL` is not an integer. It's an address. You'll probably get away with it because 0 is 0, but mixing integers and addresses can get weird.

Comment: @user4581301 I will change NULL to and try running the code. Thanks

Comment: I worded that poorly. That `NULL` should not be your started problem.  It is a side-issue at best.

Comment: Good link on debugging: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @ArvindMadan You could do worse than starting at this link:  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10735/how-to-most-effectively-debug-code

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for the link and suggestion :)

Comment: In the case of the read error, you are not initializing the `input_instruction` and `output_instruction` pointers to point at anything, so you crash when you try to access their inner members.  In the case of the write error, you did not show how you are initializing your `instructions` pointers. Also, your `while` loop is not checking to make sure it does not go out of bounds of your `array_code_line` array, if the file has more than 1000 lines in it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have added the lines where I initialized the instructions pointer. Can you take a look at it and tell me if anything's wrong?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm sorry about that. I will try reproducing my question with minimal code. Should I post a new question or will edit do it?

Comment: @ArvindMadan: You **declared** the `instructions` pointer, but you did not **initialize** it to point at anything. You seem to have a lot of trouble understanding what pointers are and how they work. I suggest you stop what you are doing and get yourself a good C++ book.  There are plenty available.  Asking for tutorials is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you. But I have to submit this code in 3 days now. Instead of using pointers, can I directly modify the variables? If so, I'd just change my code to do that.

Comment: @ArvindMadan: "*I have to submit this code*" - that means you are taking a class in C++ programming, right?  In which case, you should be talking to your instructor about this, not asking for help in an online forum. If you don't understand the material, the instructor is not doing his/her job well enough.